# Blazor WebAssembly Navigation

Tags: c#, async-await, webassembly, blazor-client-side

I am trying to create CRUD using Blazor client side Preview (WebAssembly). I am calling CreateTodo() method on button click as given below.

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" @onclick="@(async () => await CreateTodo())">Create</button>`

```
protected async Task CreateTodo(){
        await Http.SendJsonAsync(HttpMethod.Post, "https://localhost:44327/api/ToDoes", toDoItem);
        navigation.NavigateTo("/todos");
    }
```

In the above code

```
 navigation.NavigateTo("/todos");
```

The Object is submitted on server side but NavigateTo method is not called.
Can anybody please guide me. I am new to this stuff.

Comment: Does it work without the first line? I have checked my code and noticed that I haven't used "/" at the beginning of the navigation page (e.g "todos" instead of "/todos"))

Comment: yes it works without 1st line @Celal Ergün

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing button type to type="button" instead of type="submit" solved my Problem. For more details you may visit 
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/15564#issuecomment-460101825